In excel Find the names of top 5 students from largest to smallest marks even if they have same marks that is "99" but name should be change

I have used this:
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10, MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$10,1),$C$2:$C$10,0))
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10, MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$10,2),$C$2:$C$10,0))
but names are not changing

If your version of Excel supports Dynamic Array formulas, =TAKE(SORTBY(B2:B10,C2:C10,-1),5)?

not working this

i want output like jimmy, mia, sam, zakit, astha according to marks

Or, shorter with SORT() --> =TAKE(SORT(B2:C10,2,-1),5,1)

not working this also

What do you mean by not working ? It can be many thing to many people --> • Not working and giving wrong output • Not working showing error • Not working ?? Please precisely explain.

showing #name?  in excel

@SolarMike Sir, already has an answer for your query, please try to research the forum: Take a look here

You have been given a link to my method, try it, and be certain it works. If it fails then you need to check your data and execution.
